# Extend the association of a has_many in Rails on the foreign key

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Bit of a strange one maybe. But the relationship between two models is optional. The User model has_many Deadlines, but the User field in the deadline is optional. If it's not filled, the deadline is a general one and is valid for all users.

In determining the has_many relationshop, I want to not only look for records in the Deadline model that have the user_id of the current object, but also for nil values.

I tried this, but it doesn't work:

```
  has_many :deadlines, -> (object){where(user: [nil, object.id])}, foreign_key:''
```

The Query keeps including the original where and attaches the custom one as an AND, which does not result in the correct query.

```
SELECT "deadlines".* FROM "deadlines" WHERE "deadlines"."user_id" = $1 AND ("deadlines"."user_id" = 1 OR "deadlines"."user_id" IS NULL)  [["user_id", 1]]
```

How can I make Rails return the correct Query:

```
SELECT "deadlines".* FROM "deadlines" WHERE ("deadlines"."user_id" = 1 OR "deadlines"."user_id" IS NULL)
```

Comment: has_many : deadlines, -> (object) { 
           where("user_id = ? OR user_id = ?", nil, object.id)
         } Can you please try this

Comment: Isn't that exactly the same?

Comment: When passing your query data in an array will default take you to the AND condition. When you want OR condition, it will be better to explicitly write it.

Comment: This still triggers an AND query between the automated WHERE and the custom WHERE. So unfortunataly, this is not the solution.

Comment: Can you tell what is the automated where condition you get?

Comment: Look at the first SQL Query in the question. As you can see in the WHERE clause, that it starts with the automated relationship RAILS generates for the has_many and amends it with the OR part that comes behind it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always put plain SQL into `where` clause:

```
has_many :deadlines, -> (object) { where("deadlines.user_id = #{object.id} OR deadlines.user_id IS NULL") }
```

Alternatively, you can use plain plain SQL with [`execute`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/DatabaseStatements.html#method-i-execute):

```
has_many :deadlines, lambda { |object|
  pg_result = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("SELECT * FROM deadlines WHERE deadlines.user_id = #{object.id} OR deadlines.user_id IS NULL")
  Deadline.where(id: pg_result.map { |deadline| deadline['id'] })
}
```

Comment: This still combines the original association WHERE clause with the added WHERE clause using AND. This does not result in the SQL I'm looking for. I need a way to prevent the default WHERE and replace it with my custom clause.

Comment: Looks good, is the returned object still chainable with additional where's or order's? I guess not because it seems that the SQL is already executed within this statement. Is there really no rails way of solving this?

Comment: @bo-oz `deadlines` object is an ActiveRecord relation and it is perfectly chainable :)

Comment: Why was this answer accepted? The OP was asking how to make ActiveRecord stop appending the `AND #{relation}.#{foreign_key} = #{id}` to the `where` clause, but this answer doesn't do that